# Can we use the filter override feature on third party controllers?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I've developed an `ActionFilterAttribute` that is applied globally by adding it to the `GlobalFilterCollection`. Now I'd like to exclude one specific controller from this filter. If it was my own controller, I could use the new filter override feature from ASP.NET MVC 5 (`IOverrideFilter`). But this specific controller is in a third party assembly that I reference ([Elmah.MVC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Elmah.MVC/) to be specific). Is there any way to do this?

Right now I'm checking the `filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]` value in my `ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecuting` method and exit early if I find the third party controller. But I'd like to not have that code in there if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tried this solution, but think should work -

Provide custom implementation of the **IFilterProvider** and In the GetFilters get only those filters which you want to apply to controller. Here you can have any custom check like if controller is inheriting from application specific base controller or if controller is from current application assembly

```
   public virtual IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)

        {
            // Add check if controller is inheriteted from your application specific   base controller     
            //OR     
            // Controller is from your Application Assembly    
           //OR
           //You can add some custom logic to select list of controllers to skip here
            if (controllerContext.Controller != null)
            {
                foreach (FilterAttribute attr in GetControllerAttributes(controllerContext, actionDescriptor))
                {
                    yield return new Filter(attr, FilterScope.Controller, order: null);
                }
                foreach (FilterAttribute attr in GetActionAttributes(controllerContext, actionDescriptor))
                {
                    yield return new Filter(attr, FilterScope.Action, order: null);
                }
            }             
        }
```